# How to retrieve data based on multiple conditions from multiple rows from two joined tables?

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

[Table 1]

[image: 1]

[Table 2]

[image: 2]

[select *]

[image: 3]

```
SELECT
    product.xid as xid,
    product.option_group_id as option_group_id,
    product.brand_id as brand_id
FROM product_promotion as product
LEFT JOIN product_promotion_to_filters as filters
   ON(filters.product_xid = product.xid)
WHERE (filters.options_xid = '04320095' and filters.value_xid = '50073608') and (filters.options_xid = '85047331' and filters.value_xid = '77933356')
```

No value is returned. empty query

My problem with the where part. Value does not match because multiple rows are returned

The result I want in the condition section is to only get the matching records from multiple preferences.

WHERE (filters.options_xid = '04320095' and filters.value_xid = '50073608') and (filters.options_xid = '85047331' and filters.value_xid = '77933356')

As a result of this query, I want only the data with xid 27145569 to come

Since there is no data in one row, I can only make one condition, but sometimes 2-3 or more conditions need to be matched.

This is how I found the solution.

```
WHERE CONCAT(filters.options_xid,filters.value_xid) IN ('0432009550073608', '8504733163299671') HAVING COUNT(product.xid) >= 2;
```

Comment: Please edit the question and include data samples as plain text not images.

Comment: its not clear wht you want

Comment: Looks like you are confusing ```AND``` / ```OR```

Comment: Your sample data doesn't contain the columns you are referencing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN command to filter the result in WHERE clause.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: didn't work options_xid and value_xid must match together